# How to use re.split for commas and periods?

Tags: python, regex, split

I have multiple strings where words are split with commas or periods:

```
string = ['apple,pear,grapes,carrot.cabbage,veggies.fruit,yard']
```

I would like to split this based on commas and periods:

```
string = ['apple','pear','grapes','carrot','cabbage','veggies','fruit','yard']
```

I only know how to use one condition for re.split:

```
re.split(',',string)
```

this won't split words that have periods in between. How can I split the whole string so that words are split when there are commas or periods in between?

Comment: The split parameter is a regex; use `r"[.,]"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'apple,pear,grapes,carrot.cabbage,veggies.fruit,yard'
>>> re.split(',|\.',string)
['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'carrot', 'cabbage', 'veggies', 'fruit', 'yard']
```

This splits on either `,` or `.` (which must be escaped as `\.`) using the alteration operator `|`.

It can also be written with a character class:

```
>>> re.split('[,.]',string)
['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'carrot', 'cabbage', 'veggies', 'fruit', 'yard']
```

But this is less general as neither character could be replaced with a phrase.

Comment: You could also use a characters class

Comment: In _[,.]_ you don't have to escape dot. And for single-character choice square brackets are preferred option

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
string = 'apple,pear,grapes,carrot.cabbage,veggies.fruit,yard'
arr = re.split('[,.]', string)
print(arr)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the period in a character class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools` module in order to handle your list, if you have many elements in your string variable

```
from itertools import chain

string = ['apple,pear,grapes,carrot.cabbage,veggies.fruit,yard']
final = list(chain.from_iterable(re.split(',', k) for k in string))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'carrot.cabbage', 'veggies.fruit', 'yard']
```

And you can change only the pattern inside `re.split()` to split between `','` and `'.'`:

```
from itertools import chain

string = ['apple,pear,grapes,carrot.cabbage,veggies.fruit,yard']
final = list(chain.from_iterable(re.split('[,.]', k) for k in string))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'grapes', 'carrot', 'cabbage', 'veggies', 'fruit', 'yard']
```