# Split String based on multiple Regex matches

Tags: python, regex, string, split

First of all, I checked these previous posts, and did not help me. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/split-string-based-on-regex) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171045/how-to-use-regex-to-parse-a-number-from-html) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099714/how-to-use-re-split-for-commas-and-periods)
I have this string (or a similar case could be) that need to be handled with regex:

> "Text Table 6-2:  Management of children study and actions"

1. What I am supposed to do is detect the word **Table** and the word(s) before if existed
2. detect the numbers following and they can be in this format: `6 or 6-2 or 66-22 or 66-2`
3. Finally the rest of the string (in this case: **Management of children study and actions**)

After doing so, the return value must be like this:

```py
return 1 and 2 as one string, the rest as another string
e.g. returned value must look like this: Text Table 6-2, Management of children study and actions
```

Below is my code:

```py
mystr = "Text Table 6-2:    Management of children study and actions"


if re.match("([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])?(figure|list|table|Figure|List|Table)[ ][0-9]([-][0-9]+)?", mystr):
    print("True matched")
    parts_of_title = re.search("([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])?(figure|list|table|Figure|List|Table)[ ][0-9]([-][0-9]+)?", mystr)
    print(parts_of_title)
    print(" ".join(parts_of_title.group().split()[0:3]), parts_of_title.group().split()[-1])
```

The first requirement is returned true as should be but the second doesn't so, I changed the code and used `compile` but the `regex` functionality changed, the code is like this:

```py
mystr = "Text Table 6-2:    Management of children study and actions"


if re.match("([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])?(figure|list|table|Figure|List|Table)[ ][0-9]([-][0-9]+)?", mystr):
    print("True matched")
    parts_of_title = re.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])?(figure|list|table|Figure|List|Table)[ ][0-9]([-][0-9]+)?").split(mystr)
    print(parts_of_title)
```

Output:

```
True matched
['', 'Text ', 'Table', '-2', ':\tManagement of children study and actions']
```

So based on this, how I can achieve this and stick to a clean and readable code? and why does using `compile` change the matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching changes because:

- In the first part, you call `.group().split()` where [`.group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) returns the full match which is a string.
- In the second part, you call `re.compile("...").split()` where [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) returns a regular expression object.

In the pattern, this part will match only a single word `[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ]`, and if this part should be in a capture group `[0-9]([-][0-9]+)?` the first (single) digit is currently not part of the capture group.

You could write the pattern writing 4 capture groups:

```
^(.*? )?((?:[Ll]ist|[Tt]able|[Ff]igure))\s+(\d+(?:-\d+)?):\s+(.+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ZIWSY/1).

```
import re

pattern = r"^(.*? )?((?:[Ll]ist|[Tt]able|[Ff]igure))\s+(\d+(?:-\d+)?):\s+(.+)"
s = "Text Table 6-2:    Management of children study and actions"
m = re.match(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

Output

```
('Text ', 'Table', '6-2', 'Management of children study and actions')
```

---

If you want point 1 and 2 as one string, then you can use 2 capture groups instead.

```
^((?:.*? )?(?:[Ll]ist|[Tt]able|[Ff]igure)\s+\d+(?:-\d+)?):\s+(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RmyrIi/1)

The output will be

```
('Text Table 6-2', 'Management of children study and actions')
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to learn the regex as you wrote? @The fourth bird

Comment: @Ahmad There a some very informative sites like https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html and https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

you have already had answers but I wanted to try your problem to train myself so I give you all the same what I found if you are interested:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)? ?(?:[Ll]ist|[Tt]able|[Ff]igure)).*?((?:[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)|(?<!-)[0-9]+): (.*)
```

And here is the link to my tests: https://regex101.com/r/7VpPM2/1